# Is Linux shared memory between C and C++ feasible?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I wrote a pure-data plugin/external, but the API is in C
so I want to write most of it in C++ instead (it's 2016, right?).

So I thought I could write the main core in C++ and have the pluggn only send/receive information to/from that core program.

First I though about sockets, would be easier to implement, but
then I read about shared memory under linux.

But is it possible to do this between c and c++?

Comment: off topic: C doesn't have to replaced with C++ just because it's 2016. If it isn't broken, don't fix it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: even on microcontrollers c++ is used nowadays, c is clearly obsolete

Comment: ok it's possible, like any example code or link ?

Comment: Really? Tell it to millions of developers in major software and hardware companies...

Comment: *c is clearly obsolete* I beg to differ.  They even released a new standard 5 years ago.  C is far from dead.

Comment: Anyway. C and C++ are *languages* you are writing executables/libraries with. And these executables/libraries are communicating/sharing data and really don't care about the language they are written. Just mind the calling conventions.

Comment: C calling conventions can directly be used and provided from within C++. Don't fool yourself. You don't need any "proxy" plugin in C and a main core in C++ – you can just write that plugin in C++, exposing a compatible C api.

Comment: @fdsfdsfdsfds see [man mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)

Comment: Usually plugins are loaded using `libdl` with `dlopen()`. It works fine between `C` and `C++`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharing memory between linux processes happens at the OS level, and it isn't really anything to do with the original language the program was written in. Both will use system calls to access the shared memory. As long as you then use it in 'raw' mode it doesn't really matter what language was used.

The exception is if you try to use the memory for structured data (i.e. structs or classes rather than 'raw' byte arrays). Then you have various language-specific quirks to contend with that have to be resolved (padding rules, vtable pointers and so on).

Answer (score 2):

C calling conventions can directly be used and provided from within C++. Don't fool yourself. You don't need any "proxy" plugin in C and a main core in C++ – you can just write that plugin in C++, exposing a compatible C API.

Anyway, you can use the POSIX/linux system functions to access shared memory from within C++. It's really just the normal C function calls that you can use directly in C++ without writing any "adapters" or so.